# App Engine: uncaught application failure

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

On all versions of the app I started getting error "uncaught application failure". I'm on python27. Errors began to appear suddenly, last app deployment was ~5 hours ago. From time to time I get the expected result but mostly I see the error. Nothing useful in the logs. Any suggestions?

Response body:

```
<html><head><title>s~lawinsidercontracts : uncaught application failure</title><body><pre>

<br></pre></body></html>
```

In logs this is looks like:

```
2013-12-20 22:22:54.987
This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.
W 2013-12-20 22:22:54.987
A problem was encountered with the process that handled this request, causing it to exit. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. (Error code 121)
```

**UPDATE:** Now I see this issue only with default version. Any of the "default versions" gets this error. Different source code does not make any difference. Temporary solved by splitting 99% of traffic to non-default version. (it's works!)
Please, note: it does not seem to be a bug in my code, I tried completely different sources, it's seems more like internal error in the instance(s) and I would like to get feedback from GAE team.

Comment: Recheck the logs. And try redeploying. I assume it works fine in the SDK?

Comment: Sure it works with SDK. Already tried redeploying. Even our hello-world-like version gives this error time to time.

Comment: Then I would guess it's either a temporary app engine problem or you have some code that does strange things, and the SDK doesn't replicate production servers in that way.

Comment: *I would like to get feedback from GAE team.* You are not likely to receive any here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 days without errors. Apparently the problem resolved itself.